# Java JDK 8 IndexedPropertyDescriptor has changed since JDK 7 with List object

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, introspection

I have a simple issue. I have a program working in Java JDK7 but it doesn't work in JDK8 because of some introspection changes.

Here is a test program to reproduce the issue:

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IntrospectionException {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyListClass.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(descriptors[i].getClass().getName() + ":" + descriptors[i].getName());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        BeanInfo info2 = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyIndexedListClass.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors2 = info2.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptors2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(descriptors2[i].getClass().getName() + ":" + descriptors2[i].getName());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        BeanInfo info3 = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyArrayClass.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors3 = info3.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptors3.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(descriptors3[i].getClass().getName() + ":" + descriptors3[i].getName());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        BeanInfo info4 = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyIndexedArrayClass.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors4 = info4.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptors4.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(descriptors4[i].getClass().getName() + ":" + descriptors4[i].getName());
        }

    }

    public class MyListClass {
        private List<String> myListClass = new ArrayList<String>();

        public List<String> getMyListClass() {
            return myListClass;
        }

        public void setMyListClass(List<String> myListClass) {
            this.myListClass = myListClass;
        }

    }

    public class MyIndexedListClass {
        private List<String> myIndexedListClass = new ArrayList<String>();

        public String getMyIndexedListClass(int index) {
            return myIndexedListClass.get(index);
        }

        public void setMyIndexedListClass(int index, String element) {
            this.myIndexedListClass.set(index, element);
        }

        public List<String> getMyIndexedListClass() {
            return myIndexedListClass;
        }

        public void setMyIndexedListClass(List<String> myIndexedListClass) {
            this.myIndexedListClass = myIndexedListClass;
        }

    }

    public class MyArrayClass {
        private String[] myArrayClass = new String[20];

        public String[] getMyArrayClass() {
            return myArrayClass;
        }

        public void setMyArrayClass(String[] myArrayClass) {
            this.myArrayClass = myArrayClass;
        }

    }

    public class MyIndexedArrayClass {
        private String[] myIndexedArrayClass = new String[20];

        public String getMyIndexedArrayClass(int index) {
            return myIndexedArrayClass[index];
        }

        public void setMyIndexedArrayClass(int index, String myValue) {
            this.myIndexedArrayClass[index] = myValue;
        }

        public String[] getMyIndexedArrayClass() {
            return myIndexedArrayClass;
        }

        public void setMyIndexedArrayClass(String[] myIndexedArrayClass) {
            this.myIndexedArrayClass = myIndexedArrayClass;
        }

    }
}
```

Here are the JDK 7 logs:

```
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:myListClass

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor:myIndexedListClass

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:myArrayClass

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor:myIndexedArrayClass
```

Here are the logs for JDK8:

```
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:myListClass

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:myIndexedListClass -> Here is the change

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:myArrayClass

java.beans.PropertyDescriptor:class
java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor:myIndexedArrayClass
```

I have to use the JDK8 really soon but this is a blocking change because my app doesn't work anymore. I have this issue with all the classes that extend the `Collection` interface (List, Map, ...)

The code is used by the library `commons-beanutils-1.8.0` from Apache Commons.

I'm looking for a solution, a workaround, to make my application work the same way as before, when using the JDK7, is there any solution? I can't use Array instead of List (because Array hasn't changed)

Here are the links to the official documentation:

JDK7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/IndexedPropertyDescriptor.html

JDK8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/IndexedPropertyDescriptor.html

---

EDIT : I found my solution, my problem was related with struts 1.3. I had to rename my indexed getter/setter in my ActionForm :
http://www.coderanch.com/t/55172/Struts/Indexed-Properties

Comment: I see no difference in your examples. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In JDK 7 the method getPropertyDescritor of BeanInfo returns 'IndexedPropertyDescriptor' for the class MyIndexedListClass and in JDK 8 returns a 'PropertyDescriptor'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the specification clearly says that an `IndexedPropertyDescriptor` may have additional array based accessor methods, nothing else. That hasn’t changed. What you have here are *conflicting* property methods defining a simple `List<String>` typed property and and an indexed `String` property of the same name. The `List` based methods were never associated with the indexed property.

So what has changed is which of the conflicting properties makes it into the `BeanInfo` and which will be dropped. This behavior might be dependent on the unspecified order of a `HashMap` or such alike. There might be other factors as well. Thus, don’t see it as a Java 7 vs. Java 8 issue, but just an implementation dependent behavior which may also change between alternative Java 7 implementations.

There are two ways to resolve this problem. You may solve the conflict by renaming one of the properties:

```
public class MyIndexedListClass {
    private List<String> myIndexedListClass = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getMyIndexedListClass(int index) {
        return myIndexedListClass.get(index);
    }

    public void setMyIndexedListClass(int index, String element) {
        this.myIndexedListClass.set(index, element);
    }

    public List<String> getMyIndexedListClassAsList() {
        return myIndexedListClass;
    }

    public void setMyIndexedListClassAsList(List<String> myIndexedListClass) {
        this.myIndexedListClass = myIndexedListClass;
    }
}
```

Then, all Java versions will behave the same, but it has the side effect of now seeing the two different properties as differently named properties.

---

The alternative is to keep the methods as is but explicitly elide the `List` based methods from the property descriptor recognition. In other words, make the behavior, which happened in one implementation and seems to be your desired one, explicit.

```
public class MyIndexedListClass {
    private List<String> myIndexedListClass = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getMyIndexedListClass(int index) {
        return myIndexedListClass.get(index);
    }
    public void setMyIndexedListClass(int index, String element) {
        this.myIndexedListClass.set(index, element);
    }
    public List<String> getMyIndexedListClass() {
        return myIndexedListClass;
    }
    public void setMyIndexedListClass(List<String> myIndexedListClass) {
        this.myIndexedListClass = myIndexedListClass;
    }
}
static // in your example all classes are inner classes
public class MyIndexedListClassBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {
  private PropertyDescriptor[] properties;

  public MyIndexedListClassBeanInfo() throws IntrospectionException {
    PropertyDescriptor[] p=Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyIndexedListClass.class,
        Introspector.IGNORE_IMMEDIATE_BEANINFO).getPropertyDescriptors();
    ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor> list=new ArrayList<>(p.length+1);
    for(PropertyDescriptor d: p)
      if(!d.getName().equals("myIndexedListClass")) list.add(d);
    list.add(new IndexedPropertyDescriptor("myIndexedListClass",
        MyIndexedListClass.class, null, null,
        "getMyIndexedListClass", "setMyIndexedListClass"));
    properties=list.toArray(new PropertyDescriptor[list.size()]);
  }

  @Override
  public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
      return properties;
  }
}
```