# Java 8 - Hiccup: Indexed property

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 has changed the Introspection feature of
BeanInfo’s getPropertyDescriptors() method. 
In Java 8 runtime the getPropertyDescriptors method doesn’t return the indexed methods.
For example if we have a class Test with the following signature

```
  class Test{
            public List<String> getCharges(){
                    return null;
            }

            public String getCharges(int index){
                    return null;
            }
   }
```

Then Java 8 returns the nonindexed (no method arguments) method –
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[name=charges; propertyType=interface java.util.List; readMethod=public java.util.List com.x.IndexPropertyTest$Test.getCharges()]

Java 7 returns the indexed method (with an argument) –
java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor[name=charges; indexedPropertyType=class java.lang.String; indexedReadMethod=public java.lang.String com.x.IndexPropertyTest$Test.getCharges(int)]

So, it will break any existing client that expects the indexed method by default. To overcome this for a legacy reflection project, I used a custom method to fetch indexed method and then returned it -

```
private Method isIndexMethodPresent(Class aClass, String method) {
    for (Method m : aClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {

        if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("get"+method) && m.getParameterTypes() != null
                && m.getParameterTypes().length == 1)
            for (Class p : m.getParameterTypes()) {
                if ("int".equals(p.getName())) {
                    return m;
                }
            }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Can you tell me if there is any default way to change this new behavior in JRE 1.8.

Comment: Java 8 *does* respect indexed method, but you have a *contradicting* method returning a `List`. For a Bean conforming indexed property, the result type of the parameterless getter must be an array. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30663238/2711488

Comment: Java 8 doesn't respect the backward compatibility contract. If some client is created with older version of Java and it didn't conform the Java bean specification of having unique getter method, still it runs fine in JRE 1.7 and returns the indexed getter property, unfortunately Java is breaking these clients.  You can use  getDeclaredMethods(), but it needs all the classes to be loaded, e.g. if a getter returns a 3dr party jar object then during reflection that 3rd party class has to be present in the classpath

Comment: There is no such “backward compatibility contract” for software violating contracts. Besides that, what you say makes no sense. The Java Beans Introspector doesn’t use magic, it also uses `getMethods()` under the hood, so if there is any unwanted side effect regarding class loading, it applies regardless of who eventually calls `getMethods()`.